# Tragedy of Linearity

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, wordplay

> My prefix is too much.
>
> My infix begs for vertical bars.
>
> My next infix has the least concern.
>
> At the end, all I have is a 'd'.
>
> Together, I imply no solution.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> OVERDETERMINED.

My previous is too much.

> OVER.

My infix begs for vertical bars.

> It isn't quite DETERMINANT (the determinant of A being |A|) but it's near enough. ... Actually, I think we just want DET, a standard abbreviation for the determinant: det A = |A|.)

My next infix has the least concern.

> The ERMINE is in little danger of extinction; mink fur is in less demand thank it once was.

At the end, all I have is a 'd'.

> The only letter remaining unaccounted for.

Together, I imply no solution.

> An OVERDETERMINED system of linear equations has no solution.